# Why does nothing run after page.goto twitter?

Tags: puppeteer

So I am running puppeteer and going to twitter, I am running the browser with headless false and saving cookies.

So my code is

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    product: 'firefox',
    headless: false,
    userDataDir: './dataDir' 
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0); 
  await page.goto('https://twitter.com/home');
  console.log("hi");
```

It goes to twitter, it saves cookies because I went ahead and logged in and the next time I ran it I was logged in but it never gets to printing out hi on the console.

When I run it with some other url, like google.com or news.ycombinator.com it works fine, but not with twitter. which makes me think they have some secret sauce running there (although I would expect google to have that same secret sauce so hmmm)

I have tried with setting wait for events on the page.goto - like for example `{waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}`but none of them improve the situation.

So anyway how can I go to Twitter with puppeteer and have that console.log show up after my page.goto.

ON EDIT: Have found that this affects FF with Puppeteer, but if I run Puppeteer with chromium do not have the problem. Would still like a solution of course, as I prefer to work in Firefox.

Comment: I haven't run it, but they're probably detecting you as a bot. Did you try puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth and/or a user agent string? Glad you're running headfully to help debug and reduce the chances of being blocked as a bot. Depending on what you're trying to do, using the Twitter API is probably best.

Comment: ok but even if they are detecting me as a bot, how do they stop they console.log that is not inside a page evaluate. I also did things in twitter that I can see actually registered so I would think they would want to keep that from happening.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but `page.goto` by default waits for the "load" event to fire, so they may have some long-running resource request that doesn't resolve. Switching to `"domcontentloaded"` intuitively seems like it'd bypass that issue, but who knows... web pages are complex. You can try blocking some resources or at least monitoring them to see what the outstanding requests are. They do want to keep bots out, so whatever they're doing seems to be working and intended. Did you try my suggestions in the top comment? Please state what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: right now the only thing I want to accomplish is to get to where the console.log runs after the page.goto, when I have that I can get to the next part. I have tried with {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"} and that didn't help either.  also networkidile0, networkidle2, and load. same behavior with all three.

Comment: Yes, `"domcontentloaded"` is the least strict, so if that doesn't resolve, nothing will. The reason I ask what you want to do is there's often a total workaround that doesn't involve `goto`. It's not exactly an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) here since `goto` is pretty standard, but half the time, providing context leads to a pretty quick resolution versus beating around the bush. Anyway, I can't offer much more help until you can confirm you've tried the usual ways of bypassing a block, namely puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth and a user agent anonymizer.

Comment: reading the puppeteer extra plugin stealth documentation it sounds like it really helps if you are running headless, which I'm not so I'm not sure if there is a point. I set the user agent to be the same as my normal firefox instance.

Comment: Yeah, it may not help, but it can't hurt, either, since it takes about one command to install and two lines of code at the top of the file. Glad you tried a UA string but I'd use [puppeteer-plugin-anonymize-ua](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua) to be sure. I'm dubious these will help since you're running heafully but it's important to start with the easy, low-hanging fruit. Anyway, my specialty is using Puppeteer itself rather than bypassing blocks, so I'll step back after this--just wanted to make sure you knew about the basic things to try.

Comment: Trying Chromium might also be worth the few minutes if you haven't yet, just to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: seems like it is a problem with firefox with puppeteer, as I can get past the await goto with chromium. which is a shame as I would prefer to work in FF.